# unable to install tensorflow model server

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to deploy my model on tensorflow serving. But I am facing issue with the installation of tensorflow model server itself. Do I need to install anything else before model server can be installed? I am using python v3.6 and tensorflow version 1.12.0 currently on VM.

**conda install tensorflow-model-server**

**pip install tensorflow-model-server**

Below are the two ways using which I am trying to install:

1. **using conda install which gives me below error.**
   Solving environment: failed
   PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
   tensorflow-model-server
2. **using pip which is says:**
   Collecting tensorflow-model-server
   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-model-server (from versions: )
   No matching distribution found for tensorflow-model-server

Answer (score 6):

Did you try to follow instruction that are provide into documentation?

At very first, you should try to Add Tensorflow Service as package source using instructions as below

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable tensorflow-model-server tensorflow-model-server-universal" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tensorflow-serving.list && \
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -


# then install 

apt-get update && apt-get install tensorflow-model-server
```

For more information, please look at link below:

[Tensorflow Serving doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/setup)

Comment: Thanks @s3nh .....I am using Windows Server 2016 datacenter as my virtual machine. .. could you please let me know how (sudo on Windows) to run this on cmd/anaconda prompt?

Comment: as documentation said, the simplest way to use serving is to use prebuilt docker images. You can find step-by-step tutorial here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker